# How to to make an average on a sum in sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataTable that stores all the order details. I need to calculate the average revenue by day of week for the given date range. For example: what's the average revenue for Mondays, for Tuesdays and so on...(make a sum of the total sales for Mondays and devide it by the number of Mondays for the given date range...).

This is how my `orderDetails` table looks:

```
orderId  itemId  price  quantity 
1          2      2.5     78
1          4      5.5     4
1          3      9.0     32
2          2      2.5     3
```

.....

Then I have an `order` table:

```
orderId  orderDate  customerId  shippingAddress lastModified
1        2/25/2016    234        34 devver red.  2/25/2016
```

.....

I tried doing this but it doesn't give me the wanted results:

```
select datepart(dw, orderdate) weekDay, sum(quantity*price)
from orderdetails o 
join orders on (orders.orderid = o.orderid) 
where orderdate >= @startDate and orderdate <= @endDate 
group by datepart(dw, Lastmodified)
```

I'm new to SQL and I can't figure out how to do this query. Can anyone help?

Comment: sum(quantity*price)/count(dw,lastmodified). this helps?

Comment: i tried and it throws an error saying that "the count function requires on argument"...

Comment: what is datepart(dw,Lastmodified)?

Comment: You can just use avg instead of sum

Comment: You have to select the same expression as you have in the group by, but those 2 datepart's are different.

Comment: sorry i really wrote datepart(dw,orderDate)-it is the day of the week which the order was placed...

Comment: i tried using avg instead of sum but that gives me the average of each day seperately and not the avg revenue from all the Mondays... for example the result was: 4 $145.9 which means for wednesdays the avg of the details was 145.9...(quantity*price)...

Answer (score 0):

try to use `sum(quantity*price/count(disctinct dw,lastModified)) from`

Comment: i tried and it throws an error that says:"incorrect syntax near dw".

Comment: sorry,,,try again `sum(quantity*price/count(disctinct lastModified))`

Comment: i tried this one and it throws an error saying:"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'." this is the query: select datepart(dw,orderdate)weekDay,sum(quantity*price/count(distinct orderdate) from orderdetails o join orders on(orders.orderid=o.orderid) group by datepart(dw,orderdate)

Comment: actually i realized that i didn't put the extra ')' before the word 'from' so i put it and then it through another error saying:"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery." This is my query:select datepart(dw,orderdate)weekDay,sum(quantity*price/count(distinct orderdate)) from orderdetails o join orders on(orders.orderid=o.orderid) group by datepart(dw,orderdate)

Comment: ok,,,what about this...sory i dont test it ,ijust think about it..
`sum(quantity*price/(select count(distinct orderdate) from order )) from `

Comment: i tried and it throws an error again: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'."

Comment: use the ` at first and last to the order word..located to the left of the number 1 of keyboard

Answer (score 0):

At first I created CTE to count weekdays for date interval:

```
;WITH dates AS (
SELECT  @startDate as d
UNION ALL
SELECT  DATEADD(day,1,d)
FROM dates
WHERE d < @endDate
), weekdays AS (
SELECT  DATENAME(weekday,d) as dw, 
        COUNT(*) dcount
FROM dates
GROUP BY DATENAME(weekday,d)
)
```

F.e. if `@startDate = '2016-05-01'`, `@endDate = '2016-07-01'` it will output:

```
dw          dcount
Friday      9
Monday      9
Saturday    8
Sunday      9
Thursday    9
Tuesday     9
Wednesday   9
```

And then join this with your tables like:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(dw, o.orderdate) day_of_week, 
        SUM(quantity*price)/dcount as average_revenue
FROM orderdetails od 
INNER JOIN orders o
    ON (o.orderid = od.orderid) 
INNER JOIN weekdays w
    ON DATENAME(dw, o.orderdate) = w.dw
WHERE o.orderdate >= @startDate AND o.orderdate <= @endDate 
GROUP BY DATENAME(dw, o.orderdate), dcount
```

Comment: when i execute the first query, it throws an error saying:"Incorrect syntax near ')'." . Also, how do i join these 2 queries? can you tell me more details how to join them since i'm quite new in sql and i don't really understand how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: At first declare variables, then add CTE part, then main query, then execute. `@startDate` and `@endDate` must be `datetime` else way you should change `SELECT  @startDate as d` with `SELECT  CAST(@startDate as datetime) as d`

Comment: THANKS A MILLION! IT WORKS PERFECTLY.

Comment: My pleasure! :) If answer helps - feel free to upvote/accept it!